# GWT DateBox and EditorErrors

Tags: gwt, gwt2, datebox, gwt-editors

What is the best way to generate/participate in validation with `EditorErrors` when a `DateBox`, which is bound to a driver, gets invalid format string.

Currently, in `DatePicker`, it marks the field red, however need to get it to participate in the `hasErrors` for a `SimpleBeanEditorDriver` parent and report this type of invalid format error from the `dateBox` to generate a custom error message for the user.